# Product options

Tags: product, custom-options

Hi I’m facing a problem where i have 2 options for a product, option 1 is the size, bottle with sizes 750ml, 550 ml, 350ml. Second option is the colors, I have black, dark blue, grey, and pink, green. Now I need to know, if the size 750ml only have color black and blue available, how do I set the option to show only this 2 colors for size 750ml? Or is there any methods I can use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible out of the box when using a simple product with product options.

I recommend you to [create a configurable product](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/tutorial-creating-a-configurable-product). This is more work when you initially set up the products because you have to create a product for every combination of size and color that you want to sell but you can make the selection work as desired and you are more flexible. E.g. you can easily and temporarily disable variations without having to delete them. Additionally you can manage the stock inventory for every variation.

Let me cite a short summary from the documentation link above in case the URL stops working. Please refer to the documentation for details.

From the manual:

> 1. Create the attributes that will be configurable by the user - for our example they will be Size and Color
> 2. Create the attribute set that will be assigned to the variant products - for our example, we’ll call it “T-shirt”
> 3. Create the individual variant products
> 4. Create the configurable product, and add the “T-shirt” attribute set
> 5. Add the individual variants to this configurable product

A few hints:

- You will want to create the two product attributes (e.g. "size" and "color") under `Catalog` > `Attributes` > `Manage Attributes`. Make sure to set the attributes to Catalog Input Type "Dropdown" as a text type doesn't work with configurable products.
- Set the "individual variant products" (e.g. the simple product which combines a color and a size) Visibility to "Not visible individually" if you only want to have one product page with dropdowns for all available sizes and colors. The variations will not show up in the category and search pages but the variations will be selectable on the product page if you set the simple products status to "Enabled", the stock to "In Stock" etc.
- Use the copy button in the product edit form to speed up the creation of products. You don't have to manually set all information for every product.
- Note that you don't have to add product images or useful description texts to every variation if you only show the configurable product by setting "Visibility".

Comment: By the way, this link explains how to accept an answer: http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers